# How to open a large number of file with for loop?

Tags: python, file

I have tab-delimited file like this

> tag1    DATA
>   tag20   DATA
>   tag4    DATA
>   tag3    DATA
>   tag10   DATA

This data has around 250000 lines. I want to sort these line into file by tag. Line begin with tag1 go into tag1.txt. Line begin with tag2 goto tag2.txt ... etc.

Is there any clever way to do this with loop ?

Comment: What way have you tried?

Comment: I tried open each file manually and use a lot of if... A little bit of brainfart got me I guess. EDIT: I go back to read my code again, I think it's pretty much equivalent to something on dailywtf....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import collections

file_data = collections.defaultdict(list)

with open("you_file") as f
    for line in file:
        tag, data  = line.split('\t', 1)
        file_data[tag].append(data) 

for file_name, data in file_data.items():
    with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
         f.write("\n".join(data))
```

Answer (score 1):

This took 5 seconds for an input file with 200000 lines.

```
with open("input.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        tag_fname, tag_data = line.split(' ',1)
        with open(tag_fname, 'a') as g:
            g.write(tag_data)
```

Comment: you know that this code will do like 200000 I/O operation (opening and closing file) which are very expensive in term of resource !!!

Comment: ... lol? If there are 200,000 files to write, then there is no getting around opening and closing 200,000 files.

Comment: Yes, I know that. That's why I mentioned that it took 5 seconds. I don't think this is a good idea, but serves the purpose for one off operations. While doing a lot of I/O operations, this code doesn't keep a lot of data in memory which can be a problem depending on `DATA` in question and number of different tags.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I have around 20-27 tags, and DATA is 1000 column, but I have memory to spare...